# Unable to login with with Facebook on Android embedded browser

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, amazon-cognito, facebook-login

I am trying to login with Facebook on Android embedded browser. My code is written in Flutter and I am using AWS Cognito user pool for this purpose. I have done the Facebook configuration in Identity provider and it is working fine when I try to hit cognito APIs from web browser and it returns me `id_token, refresh_token and access_token`. But when I try to login with Android embedded browser I get error that **For your account security, Logging into Facebook from and embedded browser is disabled** although I have enabled it from Facebook Login setting in my Facebook App.

[Here is the screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRZgK.jpg)

Comment: I am facing similar problem since last week but couldn't find the solution yet.

Comment: Any updates? If I use 8.2+ does this allow me to login the app using the facebook

Comment: Any update on this? Facing same issue. @sejn

Comment: Yes, I have added the "email", "public_profile", "user_friends" and then try to login. Then it asks the key hash and it went through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As facebook has deprecated support for login through embedded browsers. So please follow the following to fix-

1. Go to settings of Facebook --> media --> click on link open externally
2. Also, check your facebook sdk version in gradle
3. Works fine with-
   implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0'

Comment: 3rd point worked for me thanks

Comment: @Preeti - why is 8.2 working and facebook-android-sdk:latest.release not ? Where to see change logs?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has deprecated support for Facebook login from embedded browsers. You can check more details from here.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/

Comment: If I use 8.2+ does this allow me to login the app using the facebook